# Re-export all RxJS operators into single class member

Tags: angular, typescript, import, rxjs, export

Here is [code snippet](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/master/ui-ngx/src/app/modules/home/models/widget-component.models.ts#L266-L273) from open source project - Thingsboard.

```
import { forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs';
...
import { catchError, map, mergeMap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
export class WidgetContext {
...
    rxjs = {
        forkJoin,
        of,
        map,
        mergeMap,
        switchMap,
        catchError
    };
...
}
```

The goal of code is to provide developers the way to call listed RxJS operators from custom widget code.

```
self.ctx.rxjs.switchMap(...);
```

My question:

**Is it possible to re-export all available RxJS operators without listing them manually?**

Comment: The real question would be.. why? This prevents tree shaking I think?

Comment: @MikeOne `WidgetContext ` is like API so you never know beforehand what operator would be more convenient to use.

Comment: But I assume this thing will be used in an Angular app? If so, Rxjs is already there. Not enough context maybe. However, doing this will make the thing quite large as tree shaking will not shake unused operators this way.

Comment: Right, this is Angular app. But widget developer doesn't have access to whole Angular and RxJS API, only that part that is added to `WidgetContext`. Here is [widget developing guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/#basic-widget-api).

Comment: Nice! This gives some more context. Funny I see $scope in there, brings back memories .  i wonder if you maybe can do an import * as rxjs from ‘rxjs’ and then expose just rxjs on ctx?

Comment: Do you only need pipable operators? Or everything exported from rxjs?

Comment: @TobiasS. Operators, for the beginning. It would be great to have everything but as I understood *MikeOne*, my bundle will be very huge. If I have both variants, I will compare their sizes.

Comment: Well, after `import * as rxjs from ‘rxjs’` vendor bundle size increase from 2.76 to 2.80 MB, and the total size is 5.35 MB after changes

Comment: export * from 'rxjs/operators' ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MikeOne I got final solution:

```
import * as RxJS from 'rxjs';
import * as RxJSOperators from 'rxjs/operators';
...
  rxjs = {
    ...RxJS,
    ...RxJSOperators
  };
```

**The drawback**: vendor bundle size increases from 2.76 to 2.80 MB